# Why Does Copying A Sheet In A Big Workbook Cause Excel To Hang?

Tags: excel

I have a giant spreadsheet with thousands of rows and hundreds of columns and about 50 sheets.
If I copy a sheet within the workbook, even if it doesn't contain any formulae, Excel will hang (Not Responding) and consistently use 25% of each of my 4 CPUs.

However, if I insert a new sheet, select all cells on the original sheet then copy and paste there is no such issue.

Why does copying the sheet cause Excel to hang?
It is stuck on the message "Copying" in the application status bar rather than "Calculating".

Comment: How are you copying the sheet? Via highlighting all cells, or right click the worksheet tab, and "Copy"?

Comment: The first is by right-click worksheet Copy - this hangs, the second is by highlighting all and copying cells to clipboard - this doesn't hang